# How to render different colours for polygons in different folium feature group sub group?

Tags: python-3.x, folium

I have 3 categories of data :

1. Hospitals
2. Schools
3. Parks

For each category I have the locations of these features and a 500m walking pedshed. I need to put all hospital locations and their pedsheds in one folium subGroup (and so on for the other 2 categories as well).

***The problem is that the pins are coming out as different colours but the polygons are not. I need the pins and the polygons both to have the same colour.[image]***

Here, 'sgroup' is the key in the dictionary which takes values 'Hospital', 'Pri School', and 'Park' while the 'data' is the corresponding geodataframe.

```
for sgroup, data in group_dict.items():
        cat = sgroup
        sgroup = plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(all_subgroups, f'{sgroup}s')
        
        
        feature_style = {'color': icon_dict.get(cat)[2], 'weight': 0.5, 'fillOpacity': 0.25}
        
        # folium.GeoJson(data.to_crs(4326).dissolve(), style_function=lambda x: feature_style).add_to(sgroup)
        
        for poly in data.to_crs(4326).geometry:
            folium.GeoJson(poly, style_function=lambda x: feature_style).add_to(sgroup)
            
        point_locs = ITC_locs_in_the_ward.query("type == @cat").to_crs(4326)
        for lat, long, text in zip(point_locs['Latitude'], point_locs['Longitude'], point_locs['Name']):
            folium.Marker(location=[lat, long],
                          popup=text,
                          icon=folium.Icon(icon=icon_dict.get(cat)[0],
                                           color=icon_dict.get(cat)[2],
                                           prefix=icon_dict.get(cat)[1])
                         ).add_to(sgroup)
        map_with_subgroups.add_child(sgroup)
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. It turns out that you can't specify the feature_style dictionary and reference it inside the lambda function like I had done. See this SO page that talks about the same : [Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637053/folium-color-mapping-when-adding-geojson-to-the-map/53816162#53816162). Apparently, you have to put this style function dictionary inside the lambda function and also specify the color parameter (its a bit tough to explain). I just changed this line :

```
for poly in data.to_crs(4326).geometry:
    folium.GeoJson(poly, style_function=lambda x: feature_style).add_to(sgroup)
```

to this :

```
folium.GeoJson(data.to_crs(4326).dissolve(),
               style_function=lambda x, color=color: {'color': color,
                                                      'weight': 0.5,
                                                      'fillOpacity': 0.25}
                      ).add_to(sgroup)
```

Notice how I have defined the 'color' parameter in the lambda function. This is what the stack overflow question I linked above suggests.

**HOWEVER, I would like to note that if you changed this color parameter in the lambda function to this : *"color=clr"* where 'clr' is of course a variable you have defined above, the code does not work!** Maybe I don't understand lambda functions that well yet but the code works only when I specify the variable as "color=color".
Weird. But that's how it is.